# Authenticate into Twitch API using a given token

Tags: oauth, openid-connect, twitch, twitch-api

i am currently searching for a way to login into the Twitch-API using an already given id-token (oauth or even better oidc) with or without a NodeJS backend.

**Background:** I am using firebase connecting to various services next to Twitch-API such as Youtube (Google API), Twitter and Co. I want to use my id-token for each service.

The official documentation doesn't tell if that is possible or maybe i just couldn't find it.
Hopefully there is a solution just not yet documented.

I will struggle with the same problem using the other services aswell.

Thanks alot

Answer (score 1):

You absolutely would need to create your own OAuth token as it is tied to the same Client-ID as the account that generates it.

https://dev.twitch.tv/console

Authentication has it's own flow and endpoints with the way kraken v5 and helix work.

https://dev.twitch.tv/docs/authentication

With the latest changes to the API everything now requires both the Client-ID and OAuth before it will return the requested values.

https://discuss.dev.twitch.tv/t/requiring-oauth-for-helix-twitch-api-endpoints/23916

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure exactly what "id-token" is but i'm going with "twitch-user-id and access-token".

If you have a valid access token, you have access to whatever the scopes were defined when that token was generated, you can update the token with the refresh token if you need to.

You would need to supply the Client-ID of the application the token was generated for aswell.

Unless "id-token" is meant for a different system.